# VB confused by if path

Tags: vb.net

I have VB program which user is to enter grades into using an InputBox. Regardless of user input, a message box (msgbox) stating "Please enter a number" appears. How do I change this to only show this message if a number is not entered?

```
Option Strict Off

Public Class Form1

Dim totalpointsaccumultator As Object

Private Sub exitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles exitButton.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Public Sub assignButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles assignButton.Click
    Dim inputProjectPoints, inputTestPoints As String
    Dim grade, projectpoints, testpoints As String
    Dim projectcounter As Integer = 1
    Dim testcounter As Integer = 1
    Dim isconverted As Boolean
    Dim totalpointsaccumulator As Integer
    Do While projectcounter < 5
        inputProjectPoints = InputBox("Enter the points earned on project " & projectcounter, "Grade Calculator", "0")
        inputProjectPoints = projectpoints
        isconverted = Integer.TryParse(inputProjectPoints, CInt(projectpoints))
        If isconverted Then
            totalpointsaccumultator = totalpointsaccumulator + projectpoints
            projectcounter = projectcounter + 1
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number.", "Grade Calculator", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
    Loop

    Do While testcounter < 3
        inputTestPoints = InputBox("Enter the points earned on test " & testcounter, "Grade Calculator", "0")
        isconverted = Integer.TryParse(inputTestPoints, testpoints)
        If isconverted Then
            testcounter = testcounter + 1
            totalpointsaccumulator = CInt(totalpointsaccumulator + testpoints)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number.", "Grade calculator", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
    Loop

    ' assign grade
    Select Case totalpointsaccumulator
        Case Is >= 360
            grade = "A"
        Case Is >= 320
            grade = "B"
        Case Is >= 280
            grade = "C"
        Case Is >= 240
            grade = "D"
        Case Else
            grade = "F"
    End Select
    totalpointsLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(totalpointsaccumulator)
    gradeLabel.Text = grade
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I would simplify the code and then present here the smallest possible version that still produces the error. This is not the smallest possible version. Chances are high you'll find the error yourself or someone from here will find it faster.

Comment: Looks like you keep overriding your input here: " inputProjectPoints = projectpoints"

Comment: Turn Option Strict ON not off!

Answer (score 0):

```
    isconverted = Integer.TryParse(inputProjectPoints, CInt(projectpoints))
```

should be:

```
    isconverted = Integer.TryParse(inputProjectPoints, projectpoints)
```

as well as:

```
Dim grade, projectpoints, testpoints As String
```

Should be:

```
Dim grade as String
Dim projectpoints, testpoints As Integer
```

You can't pass a reference variable as a different type by trying to convert/cast it, that just returns the value in the type you requested (if possible, which is ironic considering you're use of Integer.TryParse()) it doesn't actually change the underlying type of the variable you declared.

Because of this issue, your Integer.TryParse() always fails, meaning isconverted is always false and you'll always get the message box.

Edit: Forgot to add, Plutonix is right.  Set Option Strict ON!!